# Read properties file with JSON format

Tags: json, jenkins

I have a Java code using selenium where I have a properties file which is in JSON format with multiple values and I want to use that file in Jenkins. For that I am using "This project is parameterized" option where I am selecting "File parameters" option.

So My question is How to use the JSON format in Jenkins? Am I doing is correct and what changes we have to make in code for that?
Can anyone help on this?

Answer (score 1):

The "File parameters" is not working in the way you think, it is not like Jenkins will parse file and give you something like key/value map - no.

What is it doing is follwoing , you basically upload file and then how you use it is up to you, so in other words, if that file is for you java code, set the path for that file using the JVM params (e.g. -DpropertiesFilePath = ${abc.xyz}) and then Jenkins will parse the ${abc.xyz} for you and you java code will have proper path to file.

Otherwise, if you want to use the properties inside that JSON file itself for jenkins job configuration needs, then you have to write Jenkins job using either DSL or Jenkinsfile, in which having full access to file you can use for example JsonSlupper and parse Json file and assign properties to stages or whatever you need in Jenkins job walkthrow.